# group items in a loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I want to group the items in a while loop so that first two items are wrapped in one div and then rest of them are wrapped in another div.

I'm unable to think of a way on how to do that. The problem is that the number of items in the loop varies, its not always same. I tried using following simple logic but it does not work because the number of items change. For example if there are more or less items than expected, it does not close the  tag.

```
$i = 0;
while ( $query -> have_posts() )

    if ( $i == 0 ) {
        echo '<div class="one">'
    }

    if ( $i == 2 ) {
        echo '</div>'
    }

    if ( $i >= 2 ) {
        echo '<div class="two">'
    }

    //??

    $i++;

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with -

```
$i = 0;
echo '<div class="one">';
while ( $query -> have_posts() )

    if ( $i == 2 ) {
        echo '</div><div class="two">';
    }
    //  Item
    $i++;

endwhile; 
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

just add your last div after a loop;

```
    $i = 0;
    echo '<div class="one">';
    while ( $query -> have_posts() ) {

        if ( $i == 2 ) {
            echo '</div><div class="two">';
        }

        $i++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

Comment: Missed the `;`s I think.

Comment: Still missing some of them.

Comment: Thanks, The commas are no problem but the logic will not work.

Comment: @alax why? its strongly that what u ve explained

Comment: it works now after i added this `if ( $i < 2 ) { echo "item in div 1"; } if ( $i == 2 ) { echo '</div><div class="two">'; } if ( $i >= 2 ) { echo "item in div 2"; }` . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this :

```
$i = 0;
$html = '<div class="one">';
while ( $query -> have_posts() )
{
    if ( $i == 2 ) {
        $html .= '</div><div class="two">'; // if item count is 2. close the previous div and create a new one
    }
    $i++;

}
$html .= '</div>';

echo $html;
```